# Regex Pattern, Matcher, split or pattern.split() which is the most efficient

Tags: java, regex, performance, parsing, split

I am currently trying to improve the speed of my application by playing with my way of getting the information.

I read an html page from which I get `URL` and other information. For this I mainly use `String.contains()` and `String.split()`. But I was wondering what is the most efficient way to do this. I looked a bit and tried some of those but the results are quite similar for me :/

Here is a bit of my code (some part are just here for testing) :

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\" title=\"Read ");
    //Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("Online\">");
    //Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("</a></th>");
    Pattern p4 = Pattern.compile("Online\">(.*)</a></th>");

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(inputLine.contains("<table id=\"updates\">"))
        {
            tmp = inputLine.split("<tr><th><a href=\"");
            for(String s : tmp)
            {
                if(s.contains("\" title=\"Read "))
                {
                    //url = s.split("\" title=\"Read ")[0].replace(" ", "%20");
                    //name = s.split("Online\">")[1].split("</a></th>")[0];

                    url = p.split(s)[0].replace(" ", "%20");
                    //name = p3.split(p2.split(s)[1])[0];
                    Matcher matcher = p4.matcher(s);
                    while(matcher.find())
                        name = matcher.group(1); 
                    array.add(new Object(name, url));

                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I tried here `Pattern`, `Matcher`, `split` or `pattern.split()` but I also know that there are `replaceAll or replaceFirst`.

In this case what is for you the best way to do this ?

Thanks a lot.

PS: I read here : http://chrononsystems.com/blog/hidden-evils-of-javas-stringsplit-and-stringr that `Pattern.split` was better than `split()` but I couldn't find a bigger benchmark.

----- UPDATE ----

```
                Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\" title=\"Read ");
                Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("Online\">(.*?)</a></th>");
                Matcher matcher = p2.matcher("");

                while( (inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    if( (tmp = inputLine.split("<tr><th><a href=\"")).length > 1 )
                    {
                        for(String s : tmp)
                        {
                            if(s.contains("\" title=\"Read "))
                            {

                                url = p1.split(s)[0].replace(" ", "%20");
                                if(matcher.reset(s).find())
                                    name = matcher.group(1); 
                                arrays.add(new Object(name, url));
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any string function that uses regular expressions (which are [`matches(s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), [`replaceAll(s,s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), [`replaceFirst(s,s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), [`split(s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), and [`split(s,i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)) compiles the regular expression and creates a Matcher object *every time*, which is very inefficient when used in a loop.

If you need to speed thigs up, the first step is to stop using the String functions, and instead use Pattern and Matcher directly. Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22277193/2736496) where I demonstrate this.

And ideally, you should create only a *single Matcher object*, as I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22951636/2736496).

For more regex information please check out the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Comment: That's what I read on internet that they all use Pattern. But I didn't know for `split` because I used it with `Pattern.split()` so I thought no `Matcher` was included.
Anyways I will try to apply your method as to use only one `Matcher` and reset it to apply it again.

But I am still wondering is it faster to make a `regex` to find with backlink what is between `<foo>whatIWant</foo>` or to use two split like I did ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Last question : is this regex badly done ?  `"Online\">(.*)</a></th>"`

Comment: `Pattern.split(cs)` requires no matcher, and is more efficient than `String.split(s)`, simply because the `Pattern` object already exists. If your goal is to search `<foo>whatIWant</foo>` and match `whatIWant`, then you can use `<([^>+])>.*?</\1>`. I would change your regex to `Online\">(.*?)</a></th>`, which is [reluctant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399), instead of greedy. Reluctant  goes up to the *next* match in the search string, greedy goes to *last*.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) 
just in your second post `matcher.reset(s).matches(...)` the last matches doesn't exit. :)

Comment: I don't know what "doesn't exit" means. It just returns a boolean.

Comment: I mean `matches(String)` doesn't exist in my Eclipse ^^
I updated my code, do you see something wrong ? :)

Comment: Well, it's a pretty standard function. Did you import `java.util.regex.Matcher` and `Pattern`?